# Question on uikeyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

Is it possible to change the uikeyboard button size for my application.

I mean i want to make the ui keyboard button size bigger..

Is it possible? can i change that?

If so please guide me out

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot customize the button size on a UIKeyboard.  (Although note that the keys become larger in landscape orientation.)

You could, in theory, write your own keyboard; however, you will almost certainly be unable to provide localizations for every language (including non-latin languages such as Japanese).  As a result, your app will almost certainly be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ....if i can create my own keyboard means how ?pls let me know

Comment: Hi i want in only one language - english only

Comment: I guarantee you that your app will be rejected from the App Store if you create a non-standard English-only keyboard.

Comment: There are many apps in the App store with custom keyboards (some non-internationalized).  Apple may or may not continue to accept such.

Comment: hotpaw2: hi can you pls name that apps found in app store

Comment: Korean banking apps have custom keyboards. Search "WooriBank"